# Drag and Drop not working in ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, drag-and-drop

I tried all online solutions but I could not make this fix. Drag and drop functionality is not working in Selenium with Chrome Driver. This is my code

```
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='drag1']"));
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div2']"));

//Tried this
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDrop(From, To).build().perform();

//Also this
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(From).moveByOffset(-1, -1).moveToElement(To)
        .release(To)
        .build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

I am working with ChromI tried with Chrome driver 2.15 but having an exception SessionNotCreated

Here is my HTML

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Need your suggestion - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use drag and drop you can use `sendKeys` so its do the same work as drag and drop just instead of passing elements xpath you need to pass action on page like  UP, DOWN and so on.. in my case this works

```
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform();
```